# How can i share data between different tests in the TestNG suite

Tags: testng

I have two tests residing in a testNG suite XML. I have used ITestContext to pass the data between methods in different classes but all of them residing in the same test.

But i am not sure how to pass the data between different test in the suite.

Sample suite file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="test">
 <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
 <parameter name="executionEnviroment" value="qa"/>
 <parameter name="runOnMachine" value="127.0.0.1"/>
 <parameter name="projectPath" value="D://green_sourceonvm02"/> 
 <parameter name="device" value="api"/>
 <parameter name="releaseVersion" value="4.0"/>

  <test verbose="2" name="Test A ">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="A" />
                <include name="userRating" />
            </run>
        </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.A"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test verbose="2" name="Test B ">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="B" />
            </run>
        </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.B"/>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From within the `ITestContext` you can get access to the `ISuite` object via `org.testng.ITestContext#getSuite`

Now once you have access to the `ISuite` object, you can share data using the `org.testng.ISuite#getAttribute` and `setAttribute()` methods (Just as how you did with the `ITestContext` object

Here `ISuite` represents the `<suite>` to which your `<test>` belongs to.

Comment: Hi krishnan, I have an unrelated question about testng. Please help me. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839614/how-is-this-alternative-to-testng-softassert